# Binary softmax decision boundary

Tags: classification

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.02295.pdf) paper, in figure 4:

[image]

the decision boundaries are shown for different $W1$ and $W2$s. If the softmax classification forces either $W_1.x > W_2.x$ or $W_1.x < W_2.x$ for class 1 and class 2 respectively, then the decision boundary is $(W1-W2).x = 0$ which means that that the decision boundary is perpendicular to $W1-W2$. However in this figure only in the case where $||W1|| = ||W2||$ this is visually correct. In other cases, this is not the case. If one draws $W1-W2$, it won't be perpendicular to the decision boundary.

Am I thinking right?

Comment: I didn't get how you arrived at (w1-w2).X = 0

Comment: so the decision boundary is: W1x = W2x right? because if W1x> W2x then it's class 1 and if W1x<W2x then it's class 2 so the decision boundary is W1x = W2x or W1x - W2x = 0 or (W1-W2)x = 0

Comment: I reached the same conclusion. For the middle one, decision boundary is the same as $W_2$, since $(W_1 - W_2)^{\mbox{T}}W_2=0$, meaning all the space between $W_1$ and $W_2$ must belong to green, and only the points below $W_2$ should be red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right. But I think the authors only want to emphasize that if $||1|| > ||2||$, the decision boundary will be closer to $2$ and vice versa.